# php $_REQUEST not working when passing data through android

Tags: php, android

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['body']))
{
        $body = $_REQUEST['body'];

        $api_key = "tHx7zm7eb7z3yKHtNb";
        $password = "x";
        $yourdomain = "appicmobile";


        $ticket_data = json_encode(array(
          "body" => $body
        ));


        $url = "https://$yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/32/reply";

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        $header[] = "Content-type: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$api_key:$password");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ticket_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $headers = substr($server_output, 0, $header_size);
        $response = substr($server_output, $header_size);

        if($info['http_code'] == 201)
         {
          // "Ticket created successfully, the response is given below \n";
          //echo "Response Headers are \n";
          //echo $headers."\n";
          //echo "Response Body \n";
          echo "$response";

        } 
        else 
        {
          if($info['http_code'] == 404) 
          {
            echo "Error, Please check the end point \n";
          } 
          else
          {
            echo "Error, HTTP Status Code : " . $info['http_code'] . "\n";
            echo "Headers are ".$headers;
            echo "Response are ".$response;
          }
        }

        curl_close($ch);
}
else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

While entering data through android using php shows empty.I am using volley to pass the data.
I'm trying to pass data from Android to my PHP application, but it seems to POST method is not working well, once all $_REQUEST variables are empty.
Tried all the method get,post but still not working

Comment: How does the android request look like? Can you give us the android code as well?

Comment: You can check print_r($_REQUEST); before isset($_REQUEST['body']), may be body is not there